# Migration of jsf 2.0 app to JSF 2.2 and WAS9 Composite Component Not firing event

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have an app that has been running fine until we migrated to WAS9 app server(which uses jsf2.2 by default).

1. The app has a composite component which contains a primefaces:autosuggest widget.   The widget stopped "firing" the itemSelect event.  The ajaxListener is never firing.

Everything I see says that it is coded correctly,  but nothing.
I have tried adding the "change" event,  but that event also never fires.
The only thing I have been able to make work is to make it a regular listener
<cc:attribute name="ajaxLocationListener"  method-signature="void listener()"/>
but then I do not have access to the data on the event that I need.

This is the implementation of the composite component:

```
<com:stopComponent id="Origin" 
                               customerKey="#{templateController.ordrBeanUI.orderHeaderUI.customerUniqueKey}"
                               stop="#{templateController.ordrBeanUI.orderStopListUI.orderStopList[0]}"
                               options="#{templateController.custOptionsBean.countryCodesBean}"
                               mode="#{templateController.ordrBeanUI.orderHeaderUI.shippingMode}"
                               intlModeFlag="#{templateController.ordrBeanUI.orderHeaderUI.intlModeFlag}"
                               docType="#{templateController.ordrBeanUI.orderHeaderUI.documentType}"
                               addressBookAction="#{templateController.addressBookLookUp}"
                               saveAddressAction="#{templateController.saveAddressBook}" 
                               lookAheadAction="#{templateController.obtainLocationList}"
                               ajaxListener="#{templateController.handleSelect}"
                               >
                <f:ajax execute="Origin" render="originPanel" onevent="setOrderFieldFlagsAjax"/>
            </com:stopComponent>
```

The actual StopComponent is here:

```
<html xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite" 
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" 
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:lf="http://websphere.landstar.com/jsf"
    xmlns:com="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/components">

<cc:interface displayName="locationSection">
    <cc:attribute name="customerKey" type="java.lang.Integer" />
    <cc:attribute name="stop" type="com.landstar.cust.orders.beans.OrderStopUI" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="options" type="com.landstar.cust.orders.beans.CountryCodesSelectOptionsBean" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="mode" type="java.lang.String" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="intlModeFlag" type="java.lang.Boolean" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="docType" type="java.lang.String" />
    <cc:attribute name="addressBookAction" method-signature="void actionListener(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)" required="true"/>
    <cc:attribute name="saveAddressAction" method-signature="void actionListener(javax.faces.event.ActionEvent)" /> 
    <cc:attribute name="lookAheadAction" method-signature="java.util.List obtainAddress(java.lang.String)" />
    <cc:attribute name="ajaxListener"  method-signature="void actionListener(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)" /> 
    <cc:clientBehavior name="click" event="action" targets="saveLink" />
    <cc:clientBehavior name="itemSelect" event="itemSelect" targets="stopLocationID stopLocationName" />
    <cc:clientBehavior name="dateSelect" event="dateSelect" targets="#{cc.clientId}_fromDate #{cc.clientId}_toDate" />
</cc:interface>



<p:autoComplete id="stopLocationName" value="#{cc.attrs.stop.selectedLocationName}" minQueryLength="3"
                        completeMethod="#{cc.attrs.lookAheadAction}"  forceSelection="false"
                        var="p" itemLabel="#{p.locationText}" itemValue="#{p}" size="32" maxlength="30"
                        converter="locationConverter">
                        <f:attribute name="customerKey" value="#{cc.attrs.customerKey}" />
                        <f:attribute name="searchType" value="locationName" />
                        <f:attribute name="mode" value="#{cc.attrs.mode}" />
                        <f:attribute name="geoType" value="#{cc.attrs.stop.stopInternational}" />
                        <f:attribute name="stopType" value="#{cc.clientId}"/>

                        <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{cc.attrs.ajaxLocationListener}" update="stopComponent" oncomplete="setOrderFieldFlagsPrimeFaces(xhr,status,args)" />

</p:autoComplete>



The Backing Bean is here:
@ManagedBean(name="orderController")
@ViewScoped
public class OrderController extends DocumentController implements Serializable {

}

public class DocumentController extends DateTimeConversions implements Serializable {

... 


    public void handleSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        String stopType = event.getComponent().getClientId();
        String calledFrom = "lookAhead";

        populateLocationFromAddressBook(stopType, calledFrom,
                ((LocationLookAheadBean) event.getObject()).getLocationAddressUniqueKey());
        String stopTypeStr = "";
        if (stopType != null && !stopType.trim().equals("")) {
            stopTypeStr = stopType.trim().substring(0, stopType.trim().indexOf(":"));
        }

        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addCallbackParam("location", stopTypeStr);
    }



}
```

Comment: I may be crazy but I see your are calling in `itemSelect` the method `#{cc.attrs.ajaxLocationListener}` but I don't see `ajaxLocationListener` declared in your Input parameters only `ajaxListener`.  Right?

Comment: Yes,  you are not crazy,  my example is a paired down version, The example is wrong,  the `ajaxLocationListener` really should say `ajaxlistener`.  I have a work around that uses the `{ajaxLocationListener}`  .  Sorry for the confusion.       To make this work I had to use a regular listener() but I really want it to work the way it did before we upgraded.

Comment: So all you upgraded was WAS but the PF version is the same?  I would lean towards some Mojarra issue or whaever was uses under the covers for its JSF engine.  Doesn't sound like its a PF issue right?

Comment: Correct,  we just upgraded app servers and JSF versions which are installed on the server in shared libraries,  nothing else.  Im at a loss as to what to look at next.  :-)

Comment: Don't discount some subtle JSF change between 20 and 22 and a Mojarra bug :)